# Why we use fetch_array() at some place and result() in other places?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, object

I am following the Codeigniter framework. I just learn't how to connect to database and retrieve values. My model function is :-

```
public function getAll()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM company_basic_details");

        return $query->result();

    }
```

Why do we not use `fetch_array()` or `fetch_assoc()` or `mysqli*` here. In the first OO php-mysql program I used :-

```
$query = "SELECT company_id FROM company_basic_details WHERE company_name = 'ABC'";
$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    echo $row['company_id'];
}
```

Why we use fetch_array() at some place and result() in other places?

Answer (score 2):

Look at closer. No difference?

```
$query->result()
$result->fetch_array()
```

`$query->result()` is array of associative array i.e. result set.
`$result->fetch_array()` here you fetch one row from result set i.e. associative array.

Comment: but I tried to use $result->fetch_array() in my model but I get an error. can you also explain how to use them or when to use them

Comment: Its dependant on the framework you are using. You need to learn the concepts OOP and functions to understand it completely.

Comment: @StacyJ you need `$result->result_array()` - not `fetch_array()`in CI, see my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

In CodeIgniter, `$query->result()` will return an array of objects, whereas `$query->result_array()` will return a pure array.

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: hey thanx, I'll just go thru this link

Comment: hi,I used result_array and it worked. So can we say that fetch_array or mysql_fetch_array are not used in codeigniter?

Comment: `result_array` is a CodeIgniter method that is defined in its Database class. If you're going to use the framework, you might as well use its DB class :)

Comment: @StacyJ if my answer helped solve your problem, please consider marking it as such :)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't, or shouldn't be.

result() or result_array() are the Codeigniter wrapper functions. You should always use those in CI applications.

These both are the entire result set returned. To access a single row (in a foreach, for example) you can use row() & row_array()

fetch_array() should not be used directly in CI

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Codeigniter it's normal that it comes with his own set of functions.
This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

It has the same behaviour of your fetch array. The difference is that it puts the results insinde the $row class.

Comment: An empty array is returned if there is zero rows in the result set. Not on failure.

Comment: i went to check the documentation to be 100% sure: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html Please remove that -1 or go complain with the codeigniter guys and their site

Comment: Just take a simple test. Write a wrong query so that it fails. See what is returned. Doesn't take even a minute. You don't need a manuel to do it.

Comment: from the result_object function in the db_result.php :            // In the event that query caching is on the result_id variable
  // will return FALSE since there isn't a valid SQL resource so
  // we'll simply return an empty array.
  if ($this->result_id === FALSE OR $this->num_rows() == 0)
  {
   return array();
  } No need to test it if you can read the code.

Comment: The error will be triggered on querying (before fetching). So returning anything is meaningless. 2nd, the code in question is using raw sql and not query builder. You might want to take a notice on that. Just do that simple task. Write a wrong query so that it fails. See what is returned.

Comment: Seems you just want to be right. I just said that (as the documentation states) result() can return 2 things: 1) an array of objects. 2)an empty array in case of failure. Now let's check the code. if result is called without a parameter it gets $type = 'object' and automatically returns the value from $this->result_object(). result_object() can only return 2 kind of things 1)return $this->result_object; or 2) return array(); Testing it like you do doesn't mean anything. You could trigger any error before it gets to execute the result() function. This doesn't mean my sentence was wrong.

Comment: You should set this to a local array to avoid calling the function on every loop.